# How to switch language in qTranslatex using php

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate-x

I want to switch the language in qTranslatex plugin using a php

Checkout the below code;

```
$country = 'US';

if ($country == 'US') {
    //set language english
} else {
    // set language thai
}
```

Comment: using a program , what does it mean ?

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm looking for the same solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way - use global variable:

```
$country = 'US';

if ($country == 'US') {
    $GLOBALS['q_config']['language'] = 'en';
} else {
    $GLOBALS['q_config']['language'] = 'tl';
}
```